# SQL insert into Quotes wrong

Tags: java, sql

```
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Leden VALUES (null,"+u+","+p+",'1')");
```

I'm getting the error

> java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column '(the U variable)' in 'field list';

I know for sure it is 100% the "" but i can't seem to find it where it goes wrong
any help is appreciated!

This is my whole method (I want to learn how to do it with a prepared statement)

```
    public static void connectionDB(String u, String p, String f){
{
    try {
        String username = "/////////";
        String password = "///////";
        String url = "///////////////";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        int rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Leden VALUES (null,'"+u+"','"+p+"','1')");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Database connected!");
}

}
```

Comment: rather consider working with preparedstatements and use setString, setInt to set the Variables the right way.

Comment: could u elloborate more on that @KevinEsche ?

Comment: Check out this guide: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html#inserting-parameters-into-a-preparedstatement

PreparedStatements are more safe in terms of sql injunction, which basicly means that external people are able to manipulate the sql beeing send by you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like

```
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Leden VALUES (null,'"+u+"','"+p+"','1')");
```

**Update:-**

You can also look into prepared statements because

Prepared statements are much faster when you have to run the same statement multiple times, with different data. Thats because SQL will validate the query only once, whereas if you just use a statement it will validate the query each time.

Assuming fields are A,B,C,D;
A is int and remains are strings

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO Leden"
        + "(A,B,C,D) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Hello");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "this");
preparedStatement.setString(4, "OP");]

preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Don't encourage uses for simple statement, always suggest prepared statement

Comment: I am just giving (direct)  answer to the question but yes prepared statements are better to use and provide lot of facilities still i dont know about his/her whole code so i guess it's better not to say.

Comment: We should encourage and let OP know what benefits he/she might see if they could use PreparedStatement. You dont have to quote and make you SQL look ugly!

Comment: Is there a way u could elaborate on the prepared statement, why is it so useful? compared to what I did

Comment: Thank you very much, i also found some documentation about it on the oracle site. This was very usefull!

Comment: Great and sorry for the direct answer previously thanks @SMA:)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Leden VALUES (null,'"+u+"','"+p+"','1')'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that `"` is used in SQL for objects like columns or tables, whereas `'` is used for strings. So in +u+, which seems to not exists in context of your query.

Your query itself should therefore look something like (given, that `+u+` and `+p+` are strings.

```
INSERT INTO Leden VALUES (null,'+u+','+p+','1')
```

If you need to have `"` inside your columns, it would read like

```
INSERT INTO Leden VALUES (null,'"+u+"','"+p+"','1')
```

Also I would recommend to specify the columns you are inserting to so it looks similar to:

```
INSERT INTO "Leden" ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4") VALUES (null,'+u+','+p+','1')
```

This will prevent your query from failing when extending table definition by another column.

Also using prepared statements could be a good idea here, as it helps you preventing from e.g. SQL injections.